# How to check run-time status of knitr

Tags: r, knitr

Suppose that we have an `.Rmd` (or `.Rnw`) document and and an `R` module, which are connected via `read_chunk()`. In the `R` module, we would like to have an ability to check the run-time status of `knitr`, in other words, to **verify** whether execution of the module's code chunks occurs under `knitr`'s *control*, or it's a simple `R` session. How this could be done? I thought about initializing a *global flag* in the first code chunk, where `knitr` gets loaded, but I'm not sure, if it's the best solution and even whether it would work.

**UPDATE:**

I just verified my *global variable* approach and it **didn't work**. Not sure whether I'm doing something wrong, or I don't understand the mechanics of `knitr`'s *loading* and *initialization*. I have done the following: simply initialized the flag to `FALSE` in the beginning of an `R` module and then reset the flag to `TRUE` in the first chunk in `.Rmd` document, where `knitr` gets loaded. Then I placed `print()` statement somewhere in the `R` module and ran it as `R` session and via processing `.Rmd` document. Regardless, it prints `FALSE`.

Comment: While nobody seems to be interested in answering this question, I've figured a **workaround** for my problem. I think that I can just leave both `knitr`-*specific* and *independent-R-session-specific* statements side by side in the `R` module and simply use `knitr`'s `include = FALSE` *directive* in corresponding chunks in the `.Rmd` document to **disable** the `R` session output, thus, preventing it from mixing with `knitr`'s output while in the `knitr` mode.

Comment: If you wanna be able to simply check if code is executed within a knitr context, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121933/7196903).

Comment: @SalimB Thank you for the link (+1). Will keep it in mind.