# Check if interactive markdown is being run on Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

I want to write some R markdown templates which the user can choose to either save to the hard disk as an HTML document or run interactively through Shiny Server.

I think I need some way to check which of the modes the Rmd file is being executed through ( rendered to HTML or Shiny Server ) and accordingly decide whether I want the results to be static images, etc. or whether I want interactive Shiny elements.

Is there any way to achieve this?

PS: I tried to play around with the answers to this question [how to tell if code is executed within a knitr/rmarkdown context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107908/how-to-tell-if-code-is-executed-within-a-knitr-rmarkdown-context) but wasn't able to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the best way to do this is to ask knitr what the current runtime is. To check for runtime: shiny you'd use:

```
identical(knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.runtime"), "shiny")
```